# Unable to construct JSON response in this format

Tags: java, json

I need to construct JSON response in this format

```
{
   label : "name",
   items : [
       {name : "Name1"},
       {name : "Name2"}
   ]
}
```

Inside my Servlet program i used this way

```
List list = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            list.add("Test");
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("label", "name");
        json.put("items", list.toArray());

        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

With this format , When i checked Firebug , the response is coming this way :

```
{"label":"name","items":["Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test","Test"]}
```

Please tell me how to construct in this format .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the objects inside the Array. This should work:

```
List list = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    JSONObject nextObject = new JSONObject();
    nextObject.put("name", "Name" + i);
    list.add(nextObject);
}

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("label", "name");
json.put("items", list.toArray());

response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that i want say that in the json data you wanted is a data structure where we need to put json object to the list and then put the list to a json object referance.
[I think this link will help you.](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-3_-_Encode_a_JSON_object_-_Using_Map)